# Show that the sequence of functions is monotonic in $[0, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the dyadic decomposition

For $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\in \{0, 1, 2, ..., 2^{n}-1 \}$ is defined

$$I_{k}^{n}=\left[\frac{k}{2^{n}}, \frac{k+1}{2^{n}}\right)$$

and the sequence of functions $f_{n}:[0, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by

$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n}}1_{I_{k}^{n}}(x)$$

Where for $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, the function $1_{A}$ is the characteristic of $A$ such that $1_{A}(x)=1$ if $x\in A$ and $1 _{A}(x)=0$ if $x\notin A$.

I want to show that the sequence of functions $\{f_{n} \}$ is monotonic in $[0, 1)$

Try to compute some terms of the sequence for an $x$ that is between 0 and 1, i obtained that for $x=0.5$, $f_{1}(0.50)=$, $f_2(0.50) = 0.375000$, $f_3(0.50) = 0.437500$, $f_4(0.50) = 0.468750$, $f_5(0.50) = 0.484375$, $f_6(0.50) = 0.492187$, $f_7(0.50) = 0.496094$, $\dots$

If I didn't make a mistake in the calculations, it seems that the function is increasing in that interval.

Maybe a graph of the same, is as follows

[image: graph]

So, the idea is prove that $f_{n+1} \geq f_{n}$ for all $x\in [0, 1)$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i try the following

\begin{align*}
f_{n+1}(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n+1}}1_{I_{k}^{n+1}}(x)  \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n}}1_{I_{k}^{n+1}}(x) \\
&\geq \sum_{k=0}^{2^{n+1}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n}}1_{I_{k}^{n+1}}(x)
\end{align*}

I am not clear on how to tie this inequality to $f_{n}$, any suggestions on how to work with this, is it really increasing, any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Some hints:  For each n, there is only one k that really matters. Also, the $k=k_{n+1}$ that matters for $n+1$ is almost never the same as the $k=k_n$ that matters for $n$. However, there is a simple relationship, and further if you know $k_n$, there are not many choices for $k_{n+1}.$ I would draw a little picture (and label it) representing the partition of [0,1) for n=2, and right below it the partition for $n=3$, .... so on

Comment: Could you clarify your idea a little more? I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Even though $2^n$ may be a huge number, to how many of the $I_{k}^{n}$ can $x$ belong? (And likewise, even though $2^{n+1}$ may be a huge number, to how many of the $I_{k}^{n+1}$ can $x$ belong?)

Comment: Are you trying to show that each $f_n$ is monotonic in $x$ or to show that for a fixed $x$ that $n \mapsto f_n(x)$ is non decreasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $n \in \Bbb{N}$, and $x \in [0, 1)$. Let $m$ be unique in $0, \ldots, 2^{n+1}-1$ such that $x \in I^{n+1}_m$.

Consider first the case that $m$ is even. If so, then $m = 2l$ for some $l$. As such,
\begin{align*}
\frac{m}{2^{n+1}} \le x < \frac{m+1}{2^{n+1}} &\iff \frac{l}{2^n} \le x < \frac{2l+1}{2^{n+1}} \\
&\implies \frac{l}{2^n} \le x < \frac{2l+2}{2^{n+1}} \\
&\iff \frac{l}{2^n} \le x < \frac{l+1}{2^n} \\
&\implies x \in I^n_l.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{k}{2^n}1_{I^n_k}(x) = \frac{l}{2^n} = \frac{m}{2^{n+1}} = f_{n+1}(x).$$
So, $f_n(x) \le f_{n+1}(x)$ where $m$ is even.

Now, I'll leave you to try the $m$ is odd case, because it's relatively similar. Note that, in the above case, I had to extend the interval containing $x$ to the right by $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$. In the odd case, you'll have to extend the interval to the left by the same amount. You should also find that, in the odd case, $f_n(x) < f_{n+1}(x)$. Give it a try!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have managed to find the other case but I can't conclude when replacing the value of $x$, maybe because I don't understand why $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{k}{2^n}1_{I^n_k}(x) = \frac{l}{2^n}$, could you explain a little bit please?

Comment: @Wrloord Each term in the sum is a multiple of an indicator function of a set $I^n_k$. These sets partition $[0, 1)$ into $2^n$ half-open intervals. For any given $x$, there will be exactly one $k$ such that $1_{I^n_k}(x) = 1$. For the rest, $1_{I^n_k}(x) = 0$. Now, in my solution, I showed $x \in 1_{I^n_l}$, so $1_{I^n_l}(x) = 1$, but $1_{I^n_k}(x) = 0$ for all $k \neq l$. That is, every term in $\sum_{k=0}^{2^n-1} \frac{k}{2^n}1_{I^n_k}(x)$, except the $l$th term (assuming we count from $0$) will be $0$. The result is just the $l$th term, which is $\frac{l}{2^n}$. Does that help?

Comment: Much better, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me what you are asking.

Note that $f_n(x) = {1 \over 2^n} \lfloor 2^n x\rfloor$. Since the floor function is non decreasing it follows that $x \mapsto f_n(x)$ is non decreasing.

It is also true that for a fixed $x$ that the map $n \mapsto f_n(x)$ is non decreasing. To wit, fix $x \in [0,1)$ and suppose $f_n(x) = {k \over 2^n}$.
Then $k \le 2^n x < k+1$. Hence $2k \le 2^{n+1} x$ and so $2k \le \lfloor 2^{n+1} x\rfloor$ and so $f_n(x) = {k \over 2^n}  \le {1 \over 2^{n+1}} \lfloor 2^{n+1} x\rfloor = f_{n+1}(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $0<x<1$. Because of the characteristic functions and the partition (decomposition) your big sum is, for each $n$, not much of a sum:

$$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n}}1_{I_{k}^{n}}(x)= 0+0+\cdots +0+\frac{k_n(x)}{2^n}+0+\cdots+0,$$ where $k_n(x)$ is the "address" of $x$ in the $n$th arrangement. (See picture below.)

As $n$ counts up, the denominator doubles each time: $$\dots, f_{n}(x),f_{n+1}(x),f_{n+2}(x), \dots = \dots,\frac{k_n(x)}{2^n},\frac{k_{n+1}(x)}{2\cdot2^n},\frac{k_{n+2}(x)}{4\cdot2^n}, \dots.$$ To reach your conclusion, you must see that the numerator at least doubles each time. Theo Bendit shows this algebraically(+1), but perhaps this picture illustrates it decently:

[image]

Comment: Notice that "$k_4(x)=6$" answers the question "How many sub-intervals are to the left of the one to which $x$ belongs?" Similarly for "$k_3(x)=3.$" This picture tries to show that the "number of sub-intervals to the left" doubles at least with each step of $n$.