# Prove uniform convergence in the interval

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Related with [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4776753/is-the-sequence-of-functions-uniformly-convergent-in-0-1?noredirect=1#comment10150298_4776753) question, we can see that $$f_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2^{n}-1} \frac{k}{2^{n}}1_{I_{k}^{n}}(x)$$
We can see that this sequence converges uniformly to

$$ f(x) = x $$
in $[0, 1)$, my idea is prove by definition that

for every $\epsilon >0$, we can find $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for every $n \geq n_{0}$ and every $x_{0} \in [0, 1)$, we should have

$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon
$$
Note that
$$
|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=\left |\left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor -x \right|
$$

But I don't understand the step to follow, in the post I am given an indication to continue with the proof and apparently it is easy but I don't understand what it means.

I ask again because I feel stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you're trying to use Carlyle and [copper.hat's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4775062/248286) formula for the function, then it is $f_n(x) = \lfloor 2^n x \rfloor / 2^n$, so$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|=\left |\frac{\left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor}{2^n} -x \right| = \frac{\left |\left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor - 2^nx \right|}{2^n}.$$Does that help?

Comment: @TheoBendit That last one should be dominated by $\epsilon$, but it's not so clear honestly.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, this result may be an application of Dini's theorem.

Comment: It would really help to have the definition $I_{k}^{n}$ in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, we have
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|= \frac{\left |\left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor - 2^nx \right|}{2^n}.$$
Note that the fractional part of a real number $y$, i.e. $y - \lfloor y \rfloor$ lies in $[0, 1)$. Hence,
$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)| = \frac{\left |\left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor - 2^nx \right|}{2^n} = \frac{2^n - \left\lfloor 2^n x\right\rfloor}{2^n} < \frac{1}{2^n}.$$
And, of course, as $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{2^n} \to 0$ (independently of $x$), hence $f_n \to f$ uniformly.